# CI: generate migration on model change

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does a utility exist in Codeigniter to automatically generate a [migration script](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html) when a model or schema changes? If so, where is it?

Comment: I don't think a django style implementation exists, or even could in a sane way (it seems like that's what you're hoping for). However, I'm interested to see a good answer to this as it is a very common source of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such utility exists. Though it would definitely be a fantastic one. You could write one to monitor changes in db structure, though that might be a monster project. Alternatively, A library could be written to provide that feature.